# Using qoppa to create pdf with table structure just like we do using itext pdf library

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

[Sample pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHfYN.jpg)

A sample pdf is shown in image. We need to create 2 column structure which can have text/images/figures etc. Moreover, we need to change the text format like font/size, auto wrapping etc. Text content will be dynamic as we don't know the content at compile time hence, it should be able to align itself after paragraph ends and we should not need to provide hard coded value for height. Giving absolute positions of components in qoppa to create pdf is not feasible for us because of dynamic content.

We've already explored qoppa library and we couldn't figure out how to make a pdf like shown in image. If anyone has worked on qoppa, Please do share the valuable resources available online related to qoppa. And Please, let me know if it is possible to create a pdf like this using qoppa.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer of this problem. Qoppa provide tabular layout but in my case its not wrapping text to paragraph.